# Parsing Access Code

Tags: ms-access

I have a search form I creating in access with a code to search for keywords and then create a table with the results:

```
Like"*"&[FORMS]![Search_Form]![KW_Text]&"*"
```

WHich basically tells it to read the keyword i type in and pull up any matching results.
I would like to be able to type in multiple words, in the table containing all the data I have multiple keywords for each bit of data all separated by comas. So if I type in Manager it returns all results with the word Manager in it, I would like to be able to type in Manager, Supervisor and have it return all results for manager and all results for supervisor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SPLIT()` function in VBA to split the search string into an array, then `For Each` through the array to build up a search/filter string such as

```
(thing LIKE "*Manager*") OR (thing LIKE "*Supervisor*")
```

Comment: So what would it look like?

Answer (score 0):

I use this code. It create a OR between your sting separated by a space. I put this processed string in an querydefs

```
Function CreateOr(MyCriteria As String, MyField As String) As String

Dim MyChar As String
Dim MyUniqueCriteria As String
Dim MyFinalCriteria As String
Dim I, j As Integer

j = 0
For I = 1 To Len(MyCriteria)
   MyChar = Mid(MyCriteria, I, 1)

   If MyChar = " " Then

        If j = 0 Then
             MyFinalCriteria = MyFinalCriteria & MyField & "=" & MyUniqueCriteria
        Else
             MyFinalCriteria = MyFinalCriteria & " or " & MyField & "=" & MyUniqueCriteria
        End If

        MyUniqueCriteria = ""
        j = j + 1
   Else
        MyUniqueCriteria = MyUniqueCriteria & MyChar
   End If

Next

CreateOr = MyFinalCriteria

End Function
```

Hope it help you

Comment: Parsing is new to me, where exactly is the parsing taking place?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the question. This is possibly better.